# Lodash: Loop through array of objects and compare with key/value

Tags: lodash

I am looping through an array of objects and checking to see if the id in each object is contained in an object of key/value pairs. If the id is contained in the key value pairs, then I am assigning the value as a new object property.

So let's say I have an array of objects:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "bob"
  },
 {
    id: 2,
    name: "sue"
  }
];
```

And I also have an object of key value pairs:

```
var keyValuePairs = { 1: "admin", 2: "user" }
```

I want to loop through my arrayOfObjects, and see if the id is in my keyValuePairs. If so, I want to add a new property to my arrayOfObjects to make it look like this:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "bob",
    title: "admin"
  },
 {
    id: 2,
    name: "sue",
    title: "user"
  }
];
```

I've tried this, but it is not adding the 'title' property to my arrayOfObjects. Any thoughts on how I can do this using lodash?

```
return _.map(arrayOfObjects, function(obj) {
   if(obj.id in keyValuePairs)
   {
     obj.title = keyValuePairs[obj.id]; 
   }
   return obj;
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can that easily without lodash or with the lodash equivalent, by iterating the array with `Array#map`, and if a value exists in `keyValuePairs`, assign the object, and the title to a new object:

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{"id":1,"name":"bob"},{"id":2,"name":"sue"},{"id":3,"name":"dave"}];

var keyValuePairs = { 1: "admin", 2: "user" }

var result = arrayOfObjects.map(function(o) {
  return keyValuePairs[o.id] ? Object.assign({}, o, { title: keyValuePairs[o.id] }) : o;
});

console.log(result);
```